# Why use Buildup with Unity for DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to work out why/when I'd use the BuildUp method of a Unity Container. If I have the following:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetupEnvironment()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<ILocalizingKeyHolder, FeeTypeKeyHolder>(
        typeof(FeeType).Name);    
    var keyHolderFactory = new UnityLocalizingKeyHolderFactory(container);
    var ctx = new TspDbContext(keyHolderFactory);
    ...
}
```

And I call into the keyHolderFactory in my DAL when I materialize an object via EF:

```
public override void OnObjectMaterialized(object entity)
{
    var localizableEntity = (entity as ILocalizableEntity);
    if (localizableEntity != null)
    {
        this.KeyHolderFactory.AttachKeyHolder(localizableEntity);
    }
}
```

And the keyHolderFactory is implemented as follows:

```
public class UnityLocalizingKeyHolderFactory : ILocalizingKeyHolderFactory
{
    private UnityContainer Container { get; set; }

    public UnityLocalizingKeyHolderFactory(UnityContainer container)
    {
        this.Container = container;
    }

    public void AttachKeyHolder(ILocalizableEntity localizableEntity)
    {
        localizableEntity.KeyHolder = Container.Resolve<ILocalizingKeyHolder>(
            localizableEntity.GetType().Name);
        localizableEntity.UpdateLocalizingKey();
    }
}
```

I can't actually see what benefit there is to using BuildUp to inject a LocalizingKeyHolder into the entity?

This

```
localizableEntity.KeyHolder =
    Container.Resolve<ILocalizingKeyHolder>(localizableEntity.GetType().Name);
```

seems straightforward enough. So:

1. Is BuildUp just a form of syntactic sugar whereby if I had mutiple properties to Resolve types into, then I could just use a single line of code to make it happen instead of Resolving once per property?
2. Do I have to put a Dependency attribute on to every property that I want to buildup?
3. Can i use named registrations with BuildUp?
4. What other benefits are there to using Buildup?

Comment: [Using BuildUp to Wire Up Objects Not Created by the Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660934(v=pandp.20).aspx)

Comment: @George - Thanks. I get that much but then why use it at all, since I still have to pass it to the container, what else is BuildUp doing for me that I haven't done above?